# Fading out (increasing transparency) Pygame Function Using set_alpha Not Working

Tags: pygame, transparency

I'm trying to make a function that fades OUT (increases the transparency of) a sprite overlay, a large color block that covers the screen. However, for some reason, only the fade-in function works as intended. The fade-out function immediately draws the sprite overlay at its max opacity (255), but doesn't show the desired fade-out effect in spite of using the same algorithm as the fade-in function does, though with different range values, of course.

EDIT:

Alright, I think I know the deal here.

The fade-out function draws the overlay over the background... and leaves it there as it keeps continuously drawing it over it like a moron.

I get it.

I'm gonna toy around with this.

Here are the two functions:

This one works:

```
def fade_in(self):

    self.FaderInUse.add(self)

    for x in range(0, 256, self.rate):
        self.colorfade.set_alpha(x)
        screen.blit( self.colorfade, ( 0, 0 ) )
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(15)

    self.FaderInUse.clear( screen, screen )
    DrawScreen()
```

This one, however, doesn't quite cut it:

```
def fade_out(self):

    self.FaderInUse.add(self)

    for x in range( 255, -1, ( self.rate * -1 ) ):
        self.colorfade.set_alpha(x)
        screen.blit( self.colorfade, ( 0, 0 ) )
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(15)

    self.FaderInUse.clear( screen, screen )
    DrawScreen()
```

Comment: *and leaves it there as it keeps continuously drawing it over it like a moron.*: Yes. You should clear the screen (fill it or draw a background image) before blittin `self.colorfade`.

Answer (score 0):

Can You show how u created the self.colorfade object. And, did you use `self.colorfade.convert_alpha()` ? You have to use convert_alpha to be able to change the alpha value of the object.